# Is there a macro photography mode in the iPhone 14?

Tags: iphone, camera

I’m a bit confused regarding this feature I thought was standard on all phones including Android. Does the iPhone 14 non pro model have the macro photography feature?

I’m looking at the iPhone 14 homepage https://www.apple.com/iphone-14/ and there’s no hits for macro and the comparison table against the 14pro does not mention macro at all. If they do differ there in that feature that seems like a huge omission.
[image: iphone 14pro vs 14]

What iPhones actually have a macro photography mode? I know a 13 pro does, so presumably 14pro does as well. Is it only the pro models that have macro?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by 'macro'. If you mean near-focus distance, then sure, the 14 isn't as good as the 13… but that's not the definition of 'macro'. The definition of macro is the ability to achieve 1:1 correlation between subject and sensor. That really makes no practical sense on a phone sensor, as they're so tiny compared to a 'proper' camera. You can achieve a very similar effect with a longer lens, from further away.

Comment: that's a good point considering technical definitions. Usually I've been able to bring the camera lens within like an inch or something I think and have sharp focus. Put another way say a 25cent quarter/coin in the frame taking up at least 80% of the small dimension of the photo all in focus. Something close to that. I know I've used a OnePlusOne doing closeup photos. My memory may be off on this, I'll try to go back and verify old photos with closeups and note the phone model in my collection.

Comment: With any phone you can dictate which physical lens you use, try using the longest, from further away than the other[s]. The end result wil be 'better' overall [less edge distortion apart from anything else] Mobile phoes' 'default' lens is far too wide to do useful macro. I had a 13 Pro Max [for a whole day before I sent it back] just to see how much better the long lenses were - they were 'better' for most things.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently not

https://www.apple.com/iphone-14-pro/specs/ has a hit for `macro`

> Macro video recording, including slo-mo and time-lapse
>
> Macro photography

https://www.apple.com/iphone-14/specs/ has no hit for `macro`.

Looking at this help page it sounds like iPhones only until very recently did not have macro capabilities. I'm completely baffled I think I've been shooting macro photos on Androids forever at least 10 years I want to say.

> Camera  on iPhone 13 Pro, iPhone 13 Pro Max, iPhone 14 Pro, and iPhone 14 Pro Max uses the Ultra Wide camera to capture macro photography—stunning close-ups in sharp focus. You can take macro photos and Live Photos, and shoot macro slow-motion and time-lapse videos.
>
> https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/take-macro-photos-and-videos-iphfaacf2eb0/ios

---

I went snooping around for how iphone macro photography was described prior to the iphone 13 release. In the iphone 13 press release on September 2021 https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/09/apple-unveils-iphone-13-pro-and-iphone-13-pro-max-more-pro-than-ever-before/ we find this text

> The pro camera system gets its biggest advancement ever with new Ultra Wide, Wide, and Telephoto cameras that capture stunning photos and video, powered by the unmatched performance of A15 Bionic, more powerful than the leading competition. These technologies enable impressive new photo capabilities never before possible on iPhone, like **macro photography on the new Ultra Wide camera** and up to 2.2x improved low-light performance on the new Wide camera.
> (emphasis mine)

This older article dated November 28, 2019 makes an interesting distinction with the term macro photography https://photovideolounge.com/1180/how-to-take-amazing-macro-photos-with-an-iphone

> Is close up photography and macro photography the same?
>
> No, technically, close up photography and macro photography are not the same. Close up photography is about getting as close as you can to your subject without the use of any accessory or application while with macro photography, the size of the image appears equal or greater than the actual size due to special apps or accessories used while shooting.

So maybe android and non pro 13 and beyond iphones were not true macros but close up instead?

---

Looking further back in Android history I found this hit on stack overflow when searching for a term that I stumbled across with this development parameter `FOCUS_MODE_MACRO` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208296/prior-to-purchasing-how-do-i-know-if-ill-be-able-to-control-an-android-phones. That post was dated 6/1/2011 and I can see random screenshots of android with the flower icon that's traditional for indicating macro in their UI. It's not clear if this is digital correction or true optical macro or some kind of actual optical autofocus.

Comment: Your edit adds the essential difference. Macro has nothing to do with how close you are, merely how close a correlation you can get between subject & sensor size. Most people's perception is simply wrong; misinformed.